How can I define the y-axis position for each article in a PDF file using the ReportLab package in Python?
I'm currently using ReportLab in Python to generate PDF documents with two frames, where each frame should display two paragraphs. However, the output I'm getting looks like the following:

My code:
def generate_pdf(output_file, df):
    doc = BaseDocTemplate(output_file, pagesize=A4, topMargin=90)
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    story = []
    

    # Create two frames for two columns
    frame_width = ((doc.width / 2) - doc.leftMargin ) + 80 # Divide the width equally between two columns
    left_frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, frame_width, doc.height - doc.topMargin, id='left_frame')
    right_frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin + frame_width, doc.bottomMargin, frame_width, doc.height - doc.topMargin, id='right_frame')

    # Create disclaimer
    disclaimer_frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height - doc.topMargin, id='disclaimer_frame')
    
    # Chart Frame
    chart_frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height - doc.topMargin, id='chart_frame')

    
    title_style = ParagraphStyle(name='Title', fontName='Helvetica-Bold', fontSize=12, leading=16)
    content_style = ParagraphStyle(name='BodyText', fontName='Helvetica', fontSize=9, leading=14)
    content_style.alignment = 0  # Justify alignment
    
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
      
        title = row['Title']
        hyperlink = row['Hyperlink']
        paragraph = row['Text']
        

        # Create a hyperlink with the title
        title_para = Paragraph(f'<a href="{hyperlink}">{title}</a>', title_style)
        story.append(title_para)
        
        # Add space between title and content
        story.append(Spacer(1, 6))  # Adjust the height as needed
        
        # Add paragraph content
        p = Paragraph(paragraph, content_style)
        story.append(p)
     
        
       
    # Define page templates for both news content and disclaimer
    news_template = PageTemplate(id='news_page', frames=[left_frame, right_frame], onPage=add_header_title)

    # Build the news content first
    doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id='news_page', frames=[left_frame, right_frame], onPage=add_header_title),
                          PageTemplate(id='charts_page', frames=[chart_frame], onPage=add_header),
                      PageTemplate(id='Disclaimer',frames=[disclaimer_frame],onPage=add_header),
                      ])
    
    doc.build(story)

The articles originated from CSV files, where I crafted the texts:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get today's date
    today_date = datetime.date.today()
    # Format the date as needed
    formatted_date = today_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    # Generate the output file name
    output_file = f"News- {formatted_date}.pdf"
    df = pd.read_excel("./02. Data/Articles.xlsx", sheet_name="articles")  
    generate_pdf(output_file, df)

